# Download image from URL in HTML/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to download image from website and that image is located to a different website. I specified image's url but it's not downloading. It just opens the picture itself in its original page but only image is displayed. I can't identify the problem. Here's my code:

```
document.querySelector("#memeDownload").addEventListener("click", function () {
    var a = $("<a>").attr("href", "https://iynmemes.netlify.app/images_memes/meme0.jpg").attr("download", "Meme(IYN").appendTo("body");
    a[0].click();
    a.remove();
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just add the `download` attribute to the link itself? I'm not clear on why you need to use a click handler to generate a new link outside the DOM and then simulate a click on that?

Comment: I think the download attribute works only if the file comes from the same origin of the client, if the page is served from a server and file is on another server it won't work. I usually send the file from the backend to perform a download, so for example if you have a page hosted on netlify, you could host some serverless functions to take in API calls for files, and send them back to be downloaded.

Comment: ah good catch @CesarePolonara, you're right, the attribute is same-origin only